# how do i collapse multiple rows of data into a single row in sas

Tags: duplicates, sas, macros

im having a hard time dealing with duplicate observations. currently, i have this output:

[image: incorrect_output]

however, i need this output (below) so i can have accurate end of year counts.

[image: correct_output]

can someone please help me create code to collapse these rows without losing data. thaanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this kind of operation, I like to use one of my favorite SAS trick:  the data step [update statement](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lestmtsref/p18w3br45er2qun1r8sfmm4grjyr.htm).
Assumption is that the data is already sorted.

```
data have;
    input id var1$ var2$ var3;
    datalines;
1 . . 100
1 a . .
1 . b .
2 c . .
2 . d 200
;
run;
```

```
data want;
update have(obs=0) have;
by id;
run;
```

```
id var1 var2 var3
1   a    b   100
2   c    d   200
```